# Javascript causes multiple syntax errors on MS Edge only

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, microsoft-edge

```
if (!slideOutObserver && doc.querySelector('.slide-out-cms')) {
        mutObv.observe(doc.querySelector('.slide-out-cms'), { attributeFilter: ['class'] });
        slideOutObserver = true;
}
```

The console error is as follows: script5022: SyntxError

Which I click on and it takes me to the above code

Any ideas or workarounds?

Entire script if needed, in this script we are showing the user a cookie consent message, which overlaps some fixed elements on the page. We are doing some other things to reposition and slide things up and down based on what elements are visible:

```
    // On document ready
$(function() {
    var cookieAckId = 'cookie-acknowledgment',
        pureCloudId = 'chatTrigger',
        slideOutClass = 'slide-out-cms.show',
        mobileContinue = 'fixed-button-container',
        slideOutObserver = false,
        consentText = 'This site uses essential cookies to function correctly. For more detailed information, please see our <a  href="//' + browser.getDomain() + '/privacy-policy/" target="_blank" class="u">privacy policy</a>. By continuing to use this website you consent to our use of cookies.',
        mutObv;

    //If the user closes/accepts the acknowledgment
    function closeAck() {
        // Remove the Acknowledgment from the page and shift floaters back
        $('#' + cookieAckId).slideUp().queue(function() {
            $(this).remove();
            repositionFloaters();
        });

        //Kill Mutation Observer
        mutObv.disconnect();

        //Kill the resize listener
        $(root).off('resize', repositionFloaters);

        //set cookie
        var d = new Date;
        d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 2);
        $.cookie('acceptedGdprCookies', 'true', {
            path: '/',
            domain: '.' + browser.getDomain(),
            expires: d,
        });
    }

    // floaters are there, let's alter their position!
    function repositionFloaters() {
        var $cookieAck = $('#' + cookieAckId),
            cookieAckHeight = 0,
            $pureCloud = $('#' + pureCloudId),
            $slideOut = $('.' + slideOutClass),
            $mobileContinue = $('.' + mobileContinue);

        if (!slideOutObserver && doc.querySelector('.slide-out-cms')) {
            mutObv.observe(doc.querySelector('.slide-out-cms'), { attributeFilter: ['class'] });
            slideOutObserver = true;
        }

        // If cookie Acknowledgment exists, grab it's height
        if ($cookieAck.length) {
            cookieAckHeight = $cookieAck.outerHeight();
        }

        // Shift up Purecloud and Slide Out if they exist
        [$pureCloud, $slideOut, $mobileContinue].forEach(function($item) {
            if ($item.length) {
                $item.css('transform', 'translateY(-' + cookieAckHeight + 'px)');
            }
        });

        // If both Slideout and purecloud exist, stop trying to observe for their addition
        if ($pureCloud.length && $slideOut.length && cookieAckHeight > 0) {
            mutObv.disconnect();
        }
    }

    // Create the Cookie Acknowledgment
    var $cookieAck = $('<div id="' + cookieAckId + '"><div class="relative"><div class="ca-text col-xs-12"><span>' + consentText + '</span><div class="ca-accept"></div></div></div>'),
        $acceptBtn = $('<button class="ca-accept-btn b">ACCEPT</button>').on('click', closeAck),
        $closeBtn = $('<span class="ca-close-btn icon-closepositive"></span>').on('click', closeAck);
    $cookieAck.append($closeBtn);
    $cookieAck.find('.ca-accept').append($acceptBtn);
    $('body').append($cookieAck);

    // Create Mutation Observer to watch for Purecloud and Slideout being added to the page
    mutObv = new MutationObserver(repositionFloaters);
    mutObv.observe(doc.body, { childList: true });

    // Add Listener if the page is resized
    $(root).on('resize', repositionFloaters);

    // Upon creating of Cookie Acknowledgment element, try to shift floaters
    repositionFloaters();
});
```

Comment: What syntax errors?

Comment: How can we help to avoid errors if we don't have any idea of which error are you talking about

Comment: all it says is, script5022: SyntaxError, when I investigate the line, it is the above code

Comment: `mutObv.observe` if this is https://caniuse.com/#search=observe then you can't use it in anything other than Chrome

Comment: @Akrion Wrong `observe`: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Please include enough code to allow others to reproduce your error in the question itself, as a [mcve].

Comment: ok, done - thank you all for taking a look

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is happens to need the answer for this, I finally solved it!

MS Edge does not like the mutation observer without the argument attributes: true.
So the correct code would look like this:

```
if (!slideOutObserver && doc.querySelector('.slide-out-cms')) {
    mutObv.observe(doc.querySelector('.slide-out-cms'), { 
        attributes: true,
        attributeFilter: ['class'] 
    });
}
```